# How can we Interface between Matlab and ROS

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interface, ros

I have a face recognition program developed in matlab , I want to get results or output in robot operating system (ROS) also installed on my computer both matlab and ROS are on Ubuntu.

*How can I interface both matlab and ROS?*

Comment: There is a Robotic System toolbox available in 15a that can do this. http://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There is ROS io matlab package, have a look here
http://www.brendanandrade.com/2014/02/12/ros-i0-getting-started-with-mathworks-new-ros-package-for-matlab-p1/

Matlab 2015 is supporting ROS as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect matlab with ROS with the Matlab-ROS toolbox.

There are plenty of matlab-ros guides available, such as:
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/ros/ug/work-with-basic-ros-messages.html

The approach of such guides is commonly:

- Set up connection (e.g. set ROS_IP / ROS_MASTER_URI, create a ros-1 core if you have none running yet)
- Create a matlab publisher object that streams your data (messagetype of your choice, depending on the results you want to output) on a topic.
- Connect other components by setting up subscribers (on matlab or in other frameworks) that listen to updates on the specified topics.

Matlab-ROS-toolbox allows interfacing with ros on both Windows and Linux, which does not require you to install ROS on your device.

Having ROS installed allows various features such as interaction through terminal (e.g. rostopic list).